# Creating a New Column in one Table Based on the Query of Another Table

Tags: sql

I have a Database that has a Materials Table. I need to create a NEW table where the Materials.Refines_To Rows are now Columns from the original.

Example:

```
MATERIALS TABLE
ID    NAME    REFINES_TO
1     Ore1      Nuggets
2     Ore2      Simple Paste

NEW TABLE
ID   "in this case Nuggets"   "Simple Paste"
1              5                    2
```

This way I can reference what Materials are needed for a crafting item in another Table later.Only need to create the New table once. I can append to it any new materials later as they are created.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried googling the terms "sql crosstab", or "sql pivot"?

Comment: Where are you getting the values under `nuggets`, etc?  Also how do you decide what `ID` to select?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the number values 5 and 2 from?
Assuming there is a column in materials, named quantity with this value...

```
create table refines_to
(
  id integer,
  name string,
  nuggets integer,
  simple_paste integer
}

insert into refines_to (name, nuggets, simple_paste)
(select MX.name,
        (select MN.quantity from materials MN where MX.name = MN.name and MN.REFINES_TO = 'Nuggets'),
        (select MP.quantity from materials MP where MX.name = MP.name and MN.REFINES_TO = 'Simple Paste'),
 from materials MX group by name)
```

It's not pretty or efficient, but good enough for throw away code.